# NSData+AESCrypt.h: CCCryptor produces different results when using iOS7 instead of iOS6

Tags: objective-c, encryption, ios7

I'm using this library available on github: https://gist.github.com/Harinder/1243257

I'm debugging both in an iPad2 (having ios6) and in a iPad-mini (retina having iOS7) this following method:

```
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted );

if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
{
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
}

free( buffer ); //free the buffer
return nil;
```

}

Using any encrypted key (which has previously been encrypted on iPad2), I can't decrypt correctly anymore on the iPad-mini.

**Debugging on iPad2 with iOS6**

I can see that the method output "numBytesDecrypted = 40" when executed on the iPad2:

**Debugging on iPad-mini with iOS7**

Meanwhile the same method produces "numBytesDecrypted = 32" when running on the iPad-mini:

Does anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Found the solution here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825348/aes256-encryption-decryption-error-ios-sdk-7/18894560#18894560][1]

It works perfectly in my case.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825348/aes256-encryption-decryption-error-ios-sdk-7/18894560#18894560

Comment: As a class project that code is OK but should not be used for securing data in a real world app.

Answer (score 0):

Verify all inputs to CCCrypt on iOS6 and iOS7 with hex data dumps, there will be a difference.

Note, the "Harinder / NSData+AESCrypt.h" method is old enough that it is no longer best practice, a better alternative is [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) by Rob Napier. Among other things the password should be converted to key with a Password-Based Key Derivation Function such as PBKDF2. Also using CBC mode (the default) without an iv has known weaknesses.